# Find attached child objects of a-frame/ a-marker

Tags: aframe

I have a small A-frame based program to render text on a marker. When user click on the marker, I would like to scale the text, so it will be more visible. I can capture the click-event on the marker but how can I get it's child entities to scale?

My code can be found in https://codepen.io/asatrash/pen/rNLMgpa

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
            <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>   
      </head>
    <body>


    <script>
      //Multi Markers WebAR-AR.js and Aframe - Playing the Archive - Connected Environment CASA-UCL

      //Global Variable
      var markersURLArray=[];
      var markersNameArray=[];
      var allow_clicks = false;

      AFRAME.registerComponent('markers_start',{
        init:function(){
          console.log('Add markers to the scene');

          var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
          
          //list of the markers
          for(var i=1; i<6; i++)`enter code here`
          {
            var url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asatrash/ARInWeb/main/resources/markers/pattern-Individual_Blocks-3.patt";
            markersURLArray.push(url);
            markersNameArray.push('Marker_'+i);
            //console.log(url);
          }

          for(var k=0; k<5; k++)
          {
            var markerEl = document.createElement('a-marker');
            markerEl.setAttribute('type','pattern');
            markerEl.setAttribute('url',markersURLArray[k]);
            markerEl.setAttribute('id',markersNameArray[k]);

            markerEl.setAttribute('registerevents','');
            sceneEl.appendChild(markerEl);


            var boxEl = document.createElement('a-box');
            boxEl.setAttribute('id','box');
            boxEl.setAttribute('depth','0.001');
            boxEl.setAttribute('width','6');
            boxEl.setAttribute('height','4');
            boxEl.setAttribute('opacity','0.25');
            boxEl.setAttribute('position','0 -2 -4');
            boxEl.setAttribute('rotation','0 0 0');
            boxEl.setAttribute('material', {color: '#000000'});
            markerEl.appendChild(boxEl);


            var textEl = document.createElement('a-text');
            textEl.setAttribute('id','text');
            textEl.setAttribute('text',{color: '#ffff00',  align: 'left', value:'This is a very log text /b \n line which might or might not wrap', width: '2' });
            //textEl.setAttribute('position', '-1.4 1.5 0');
            textEl.setAttribute('position', '-2.5 1.5 0')
            textEl.setAttribute('scale', '2 2 0'); 
            boxEl.appendChild(textEl); 
          }            
       
        }
        
      });


      //Detect marker found and lost
      AFRAME.registerComponent('registerevents', {
          init: function () {
            const marker = this.el;
            

            marker.addEventListener("markerFound", ()=> {
              var markerId = marker.id;
              console.log('Marker Found: ', markerId);
              allow_clicks = true;
            });

            marker.addEventListener("markerLost",() =>{
              var markerId = marker.id;
              console.log('Marker Lost: ', markerId);
              allow_clicks = false;
            });
            
             marker.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
                  if (allow_clicks){
                     console.log("CLICKED!!!" + marker.id);
                    //I want to scale the box and the text attached to the marker jere
                  }            
            });
          },
        });

        </script> 

        <a-scene markers_start vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" color-space="sRGB" renderer="gammaOutput: true"
            embedded arjs='debugUIEnabled: false; sourceType: webcam; patternRatio: 0.85; trackingMethod: best;'> 
              <a-entity id='userCamera' camera look-controls > 
                <a-cursor> </a-cursor> 
              </a-entity> 
        </a-scene>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did bit more testing and found out the following.

1. The 'click' event doesn't work as I expected on the marker. It is registered to the whole scene and it get invoked irrespective of the place I click. Which is not what I want. I am looking at using intersection Points to get it working.
2. However the getting access to the child can be easily done if you put unique ids. We can use the normal document.getElementById("boxelementId"); and change the attributes using the setAttribute method.

Ex: To change the text

```
var markerTextEl = document.getElementById(markerTextxId);
markerTextEl.setAttribute("value", "Current Temperature is: " + data);
```

I used above inside the 'markerFound' event to show different/current value when user point to a particular marker.